# Creating Classes using Entity data model

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I am a newbie for Entity frame work..I have to setup our project solution..and I am struggling to create all classes according to our database..

Is there any way to create classes using entity data model?

I tried with PCOCO but I don't know how to customize it.  I got the .tt file and child classes; all those class properties contains the foreign key relations too.  How can I get plain classes without any relations?

Please provide me a way to create classes according to the tables in the database..
otherwise I have to manually create all .cs files..i have more than 50 tables in our database..manually creating all those classes are really painful...

Please tell me how to convert those business access layer classes to DAL classes once i got the classes...is their any way to write a global class or method which will do the mapping...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your tt template that generates your code and simply remove all statements referring to the navigation properties.

Answer (score 0):

Use Entity Data Model (designer) and choose Update from database (from context menu in designer). If you want to use [Foreign keys columns](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msdnforum/archive/2010/05/07/foreign-key-association-in-entity-framework-4.aspx) in your classes as well do not forget to check "Include foreign key columns in a model". Turn off auto generation in EDMX properties window and Add POCO template. POCO template will create classes exactly as defined in EDMX file. So if you don't want navigation properties you have to go and manually delete all these properties from EDMX designer. But I recommend not to do it. If you do it you will loose much of EF power. If you want to do it you probably don't fully understand EF and ORM at the moment.

Comment: ohh..thanks..yes your are correct..I am not very much familiar with EF..will u please recommend me any tutorials or sites which can explain EF very well..and also give me some advice on how to use the generated class files...if i moved all these classes to Business layer then they become business objects and no more entity..i have to find a way to convert or map all those properties to entity properties..

Comment: I recommend the book: Programming Entity Framework 2nd edition. It is definite source of information you need.

Answer (score 0):

Well may be you don't want to create the classes as EF will do that for you. You can always extend the classes using partial class and yo can also use data annotations from the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace.

Refer to Scott Guthrie's blog (in context of asp.net mvc but concept can be used elsewhere) http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx particularly the section 'But what if we are using a graphical tool for our ORM mappings?'